# Расстановка знаков препинания правильная?

Tags: пунктуация

Многие виды художественных промыслов удалось не только сохранить, но и, благодаря, в первую очередь, народным мастерам, вдохнуть в них новую жизнь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Многие виды художественных промыслов удалось не только сохранить, но и, благодаря в первую очередь народным мастерам, вдохнуть в них новую жизнь.*

В первую очередь - наречное выражение, обычно оно не обособляется, в значении вводного выражение бывает только в начале предложения в значении "во-первых" - для связи мыслей. Здесь такое значение отсутствует,поэтому обособление некорректно.

Answer (score 2):

Сочетание ***в первую очередь*** желательно не использовать:

Многие виды художественных промыслов удалось не только сохранить, но и, **благодаря  народным мастерам**, вдохнуть в них новую жизнь.

Пояснение

1) **Можно ли сочетание обособить**

Наречное выражение ***в первую очередь*** обычно не обособляется, обособление возможно при удобной позиции, например: Чаще всего подобные множества возникают в нелинейных динамических системах и, **в первую очередь,** в дискретных динамических системах.

Но в нашем случае обособление невозможно, так как обособленное сочетание будет стоять после предлога ***благодаря,*** затемняя грамматическую связь.

2) **Можно ли сочетание не обособлять**

***Благодаря народным мастерам*** ― предложное управление устойчивым сочетанием  ***народный мастер***.  Но при наличии наречного сочетания ***в первую очередь*** неясно, к чему оно относится: *благодаря (в первую очередь) народным мастерам или благодаря (в первую очередь народным) мастерам.*

К тому же в этом случае  встречаются два предлога: ***благодаря*** и ***в*** (грамматическая неясность).

3)  **Вывод**

И в целом (с точки зрения фонетической сочетаемости слов) выражение  **благодаря в первую очередь народным мастерам** читается не лучшим образом, поэтому ***в первую очередь*** лучше опустить.

Comment: поправьте, пожалуйста, ответ : _прежде всего_ в вопросе нет.

Comment: Спасибо, исправила.